# how to rotate label of a bar chart and add offset in core plot?

Tags: core-plot

just wondering if there is a way to rotate the labels placed on bar charts and add offset to it ? Thank you.

Below my delegate implementation. Note the padding on label

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CPTMutableTextStyle *whiteTextStyle = [[[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
    whiteTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    whiteTextStyle.fontSize = 14.0f;

    CPTTextLayer *label = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"Test" style:whiteTextStyle];
    label.paddingLeft = -100.0f; // <---
    return [label autorelease];
}
```

Comment: the snipper above not does work

Answer (score 1):

Use the `labelOffset` and `labelRotation` properties on the plot. These are inherited from `CPTPlot` by all Core Plot plots.

You should not set the padding in `-dataLabelForPlot:recordIndex:`.

Comment: where should i set the padding for labels?